# Значение свойства target объекта Event

Tags: javascript

При создании обработчика событий столкнулся с непонятным поведением `Mozilla Firefox 13`.
Для обработки экземпляра события использовал не хитрый код:

```
function funcName(event){
  var event = (event)? event : window.event,
      target = (event.target)? event.target : event.srcElement; 
}
```

Дальше я работаю с этими переменными по своему усмотрению и скрипт работает в браузерах `Chrome 20, Safari 5, Opera 12, IE7-9`! Но отказывается в Mozilla 13, сообщая о том, что `target` `underfined`. Не можете подсказать по какой причине это происходит и как это поведение исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка  во втором условии. Необходимо проверять следующим образом:

```
var target = (event)? event.target : event.srcElement;
```

Очередной раз - просто невнимательность, которую другие браузеры лояльно "пропустили".

***PS***: ответ был написан мной же на случай подобной возникновения на форуме подобного вопроса.